# Stream map with Generic type

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, sonarqube, method-reference

I want clean Sonar issue after create new code in java 8.

```
public class Argument<T> {
    ...
    public T getValue() {
        return parameterType.transform(group.getValues());
    }
    ...
}
```

My code:

```
 List<Argument<?>> args = expression.match(text);
 return args == null ? null : args.stream().map(arg -> arg.getValue()).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Sonar say:

Lambdas should be replaced with method references. Method/constructor references are more compact and readable than using lambdas, and are therefore preferred. Similarly, null checks can be replaced with references to the Objects::isNull and Objects::nonNull methods.

I want change `map(arg -> arg.getValue())` by `map(T::getValue())` but is it wrong compilation ().

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Lambdas should be replaced with method references

change

```
.map(arg -> arg.getValue())
```

to

```
.map(Argument::getValue)
```

As for:

> Similarly, null checks can be replaced with references to the
>   Objects::isNull and Objects::nonNull methods

I've not used Sonar before but if it prefers the use of `Objects.isNull` and `Objects.nonNull` for null checks then you'd need to do:

```
return Objects.isNull(args) ? null : args.stream()
                .map(Argument::getValue)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```